# Perl catalyst controller redirect not working

Tags: perl, controller, catalyst

I have looked over this code and I can not understand the weirdness it exhibits. For a lack of understanding all I know

```
$c->res->redirect('qbo/home');
```

is being ignored, in favor of the redirect in the following if **else** condition. In other words, I always end up at the OAuthentication website.

If I block comment out the else condition I end up where I want to go **qbo/home**

```
sub index :Path :Args(0) {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;

    # Check to see if we have QBO::OAuth object in our user's session
    # Create new object in session if we don't already have one
    if(!($c->session->{qbo})) {
            $c->log->info('Creating QBO::OAuth, save in user session');
            $c->session->{qbo} = QBO::OAuth->new(
                    consumer_key => 'qyprddKpLkOclitN3cJCJno1fV5NzcT',
                    consumer_secret => 'ahwpSghVOzA142qOepNHoujyuHQFDbEzeGbZjEs3sPIc',
            );
    }

    # Now we set our object variable to the session old or new
    my $qbo = $c->session->{qbo};
    ######### GOTO 'qbo/home' ##########
    $c->res->redirect('qbo/home');
    ####################################
    if($c->req->params->{oauth_token}) {
            $c->log->info('Now Redirect to access_endpoint');
            # Get realmId and save it to our QBO::OAuth object in user session
            $qbo->realmId($c->req->params->{realmId});
            # Call QBO::OAuth->request_access_token
            my $r = $qbo->request_access_token($c->req->params->{oauth_verifier});
            $c->res->redirect('qbo/home');
    } else {
            my $callback = 'http://www.example.com/qbo';
            # Request a token
            my $r = $qbo->request_token($callback);
            if($qbo->has_token) {
                    #Continue on down, Redirect to auth_user_endpoint
                    $c->res->redirect($qbo->auth_user_endpoint . '?oauth_token=' . $qbo->token);
            }
    }
}
```

Seems I am missing some basic fundamental about how this works. Any clues appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Response#res-redirect-url-status)...

> This is a convenience method that sets the Location header to the redirect destination, and then sets the response status. You will want to `return` or `$c->detach()` to interrupt the normal processing flow if you want the redirect to occur straight away.

Note also the warning on that manual page about redirecting to a relative URL - you shouldn't do it. For your use-case, I'd recommend getting into the habit of using:

```
return $c->res->redirect($c->uri_for('qbo/home'));
```

or

```
$c->res->redirect($c->uri_for('qbo/home')) && $c->detach();
```

depending on your preference.

Comment: I'd go with the second suggestion, but as two statements, not with the `&&`. That's easier to read.

Comment: I suspect now the OP understands why what he had wasn't working and why, he'll be right. But I'm not convinced that "redirect and detach" isn't perfectly readable and clear. That's why we love perl though - TIMTOWTDI :-)

Comment: Well, I did manage to figure this out yesterday. Soon after I posed the question it hit me that a return statement would stop code execution. I still think I prefer option #2 now that I understand a little better. Thank you